# How to use EFI Shell to recover from SELinux Lockout?

Tags: centos, uefi

I enabled SELinux on my Centos 8 box and now I can't get back into the server. It's hosted with a company, so I don't have physical access to it. But I do have access to advanced boot options, including the EFI shell. I am thinking if I can get access to the partitions, I can disable SELinux like that. However, I don't know how to get to the files. I followed the instructions [here](https://linuxhint.com/use-uefi-interactive-shell-and-its-common-commands/) but I get stuck on this part:

```
For example, to select the storage device fs1, you can run the following command:
Shell> fs1:
```

or in my case:

```
Shell> blk0:
```

However, when I type that, I still see:

```
Shell>
```

When I am expecting to see:

```
blk0:\>
```

If I type:

```
blk9:
```

Then I get error:

```
'blk9:' is not a valid mapping
```

I dont get that if I type blk0. So it is aware of the mapping, it's just not switching folders.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you mount an iso file to boot from?

Comment: Maybe you don't even need that. Can you log in via the local console? Can you boot into single user mode?

Comment: Did you try to just set selinux to permissive mode with the grub boot options?

Comment: I ended up wiping the server and installing a new ISO. Luckily I needed Centos 7 instead of Centos 8, so I would have had to wipe it anyway. But it seems the generalk consensus is that you cant get in. I could only get into EFI console, and from there I have no idea how to access the harddrives. If I could, that would solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. An upvote would be nice as I cant currently post more questions. I have a +10k rep on stackoverflow, but somehow here nobody likes my questions :(